# How to return a suspend function, which accepts an argument?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

All of the following examples require a mutex variable.

```kotlin
val mutex = Mutex()
```

If I have an non-suspend function, I can use it create a synchronzied suspend function:

```kotlin
fun action0 () {}

suspend fun synchronizedAction0 () {
    mutex.withLock {
        action0 ()
    }
}
```

The same applies to functions with arguments:

```kotlin
fun action1 (x: T) {}

suspend fun synchronizedAction1 (x: T) {
    mutex.withLock {
        action1 (x)
    }
}
```

If I have more than one non-suspend function, I want to convert into synchronized versions, I can write a non-suspend function, which takes another non-suspend function and converts it into a suspend function.

```kotlin
fun synchronize (action0: () -> Unit): suspend () -> Unit {
    return suspend {
        mutex.withLock {
            action0 ()
        }
    }
}
```

But how to do it for an action, which requires an argument?

I tried this, but it does not compile:

```kotlin
fun synchronize (action1: (T) -> Unit): suspend (T) -> Unit {
    return suspend { x ->
        mutex.withLock {
            action1 (x)
        }
    }
}
```

The error is, that the compiler can not infer the type of parameter `x`. I think it is obvious, it is `T`. How can I tell Kotlin?

I tried this, but it does not compile either.

```kotlin
fun synchronize (action1: (T) -> Unit): suspend (T) -> Unit {
    return suspend fun (x: T) {
        mutex.withLock {
            action1 (x)
        }
    }
}
```

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we need to define `T` as a type parameter for the `synchronize()` function. Then we don't really have to specify `suspend` or argument types for the lambda - they will be automatically inferred by the compiler:

```kotlin
fun <T> synchronize (action1: (T) -> Unit): suspend (T) -> Unit {
    return { x ->
        mutex.withLock {
            action1 (x)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case `T` is a parameter of the class, which contains the functions. It is also the place, where `mutex` is stored.

Comment: Then just remove `<T>` and it should be fine.